# Video of SD Set Top Box Displayed in LCD Monitor with RCA VGA Cable

Tags: audio, video, vga, rca

I want to display the video of the standard definition set top box into a vga lcd monitor instead of a television. Is it possible without using a TV Tuner card. What if I want to do it using a VGA-RCA-CABLE? I am basically concerned about the video only and plan to redirect the audio to a sound system using the RCA cable.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A tv card will run the video inside of a window on your PC (or fullscreen if you wish). Your computer will be required to be on and logged in.

Using a VGA to RCA cable will allow you to have to have the set top box on without the computer powered on. These cables can cause issues depending on your monitor.

A powered VGA to RCA converter will also allow you to do the same.